# How do i solve error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

Everytime i use ng serve or npm start i get this error out of nowhere, everyting was working perfect but after i restarted VS code i can't run my project idk why!!
An unhandled exception occurred: error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line
See "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\ng-ewpjdi\angular-errors.log" for further details.

---

Here is angular-errors.log :

[error] Error: error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line
at node:internal/tls/secure-context:69:13
at Array.forEach ()
at setCerts (node:internal/tls/secure-context:67:3)
at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:156:5)
at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:117:3)
at Server.setSecureContext (node:_tls_wrap:1352:27)
at Server (node:_tls_wrap:1211:8)
at new Server (node:https:74:3)
at Object.createServer (node:https:112:10)
at Server.createServer (E:\project\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:2528:57)

I tried to replace that file with an old version of it but still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue when attempting to use a self-signed SSL certificate for a localhost webserver.

The problem happened because I tried using a Certificate Request file `cert-request.csr`.

A trustworthy signed certificate is signed by a Certificate Authority. So `cert-request.csr` fails to work in the application because is not a valid certificate.

To finish the SSL setup, you must sign the certificate yourself, or have it signed by a trusted Certificate Authority.

To sign it yourself, you can use a command like this:

```
openssl x509 -req -signkey private.key -in csr.csr -out certificate.crt
```

Then update your server to use the new `certificate.crt` file instead of the `.csr` file.